# Import Windows DHCP leases into a Linux DHCP Server

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I'm replacing a Windows DHCP server with an Ubuntu server.
I need to migrate leases in the new DHCP. What would be the easiest solution?

1. Create reservation in my dhcp.conf? (I would prefer have only leases that expire in few days...)
2. Create a script parsing my windows leases to recreate file dhcpd.leases?
3. Is there an existing command taking ip and MAC in argument which create a lease in dhcpd.leases? It would be much more easier to create my dhcp.leases file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I can only speak to question 3, IP address from MAC:

Yes, you can do it that way. You would do it in your `dhcpd.conf` file. Those declarations should be outside of your generic DHCP IP address pool and before them. Example:

```
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...

default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 93000;
option domain-name "smythies.com";
# option domain-name-servers 192.168.111.1, 75.154.133.68, 75.154.133.100;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.111.1;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.111.255;
option routers 192.168.111.1;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# Some specifically declared static IP addresses

host Wireless-R {
  hardware ethernet 00:22:6B:82:01:55;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.57;
}

host dwifi {
  hardware ethernet f4:8c:eb:c8:08:a0;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.58;
}

host Doug-XPS {
  hardware ethernet 00:23:4d:a6:ed:c4;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.100;
}

host Doug-XPS2 {
  hardware ethernet 00:21:9B:F9:21:26;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.101;
}

host S10 {
  hardware ethernet A0:F3:C1:10:22:EA;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.102;
}

host cyd-hp {
  hardware ethernet 70:1a:04:82:90:6f;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.103;
}

...

host serv-ff {
  hardware ethernet 52:54:00:27:1b:4e;
  fixed-address 192.168.111.217;
}

# The Basic DHCP allocated addresses

subnet 192.168.111.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.111.3 192.168.111.50;
}
```

Note that addresses given out based on MAC will not appear in your `dhcpd.leases` file.

Comment: Thanks, so your solution is corresponding to point 1 of my question. Now the problem is that I have more than 200 reservation/lease to create, so I will be obliged to develop a script to generate my dhcp.conf from my Windows leases. Except if there is already an existing command "add_reservation my_ip my_eth"?

Comment: Not that I know of, however I have never looked for such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get a very smooth transition would be to give the new server a range of addresses that doesn't overlap with the range the old server used.  Then just wait for the lease time the old server used, at which point all the old addresses are replaced, and you can expand the new server's range.  This won't work if the old server's DHCP range took up too much of the subnet, like giving out 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.254 in a 192.168.1.0/24; in that case you could cut the old server's range down, wait the lease time (setting a short lease time now will speed up next phase) for everybody to move, then proceed as above.

This is all only worthwhile if you have very hard availability requirements on the clients; otherwise, just cut over to the new server and anybody who gets their address taken away from them will have networking quit working and they'll restart it or reboot.

Comment: Thanks,
But I need host connected recently to this server keep the exactly same ip address before and after the transition. So lease migration is mandatory.